# Umbraco v9 Convert IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> search result (examine) to strongly typed models

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, umbraco, .net-5, umbraco9

I have created a ViewComponent, where it gets the search string parameter to search through Umbraco content. I have implemented the search and the possible results are of IEnumerable. This part is tested and it works.

The problem that I have is how to cast this IEnumerable into possibly more Backoffice models (ModelsBuilder C# classes)?

Another question, why doesn't Intellisense work with IPublishedContent?

[image]

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: For some reason, the stackoverflow cut out IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>, it just shows IEnumerable now

Answer (score 1):

if you know the Document Type of the content coming from the search, and it's all the same results, you can use the following:

```
var content = results.OfType<Model>();
```

assuming `results === IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>`

But quite often the results you get back from a search consist of several different Document Types, in which case you can do something like this when rendering them out:

```
foreach(var result in results) {
  if (result is PageModel1 pageModel1) 
  {
    // render out the details for a `PageModel1` Document Type based on the
    // new variable pageModel1
  }
  else if (result is PageModel2 pageModel2) 
  {
    // render out the details for a `PageModel2` Document Type based on the
    // new variable pageModel1
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I try to pass this to the model, I get an error. I made a custom model CustomSearchModel that holds all of the parsed lists and chose that as a model on razor view. Any advice on how to render this properly?

Comment: You will need to post your code and the error… then I can take a look and advise what can be done